# Is there any ruby gem which converts doc / docx / txt / odt / rtf to pdf?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, rubygems

I tried https://github.com/DocSpring/libreconv, but the template alignment/styling of document is not preserved. So can you suggest me any gem that will do the work.
Even a java-script library is fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of gems that do what you ask - one of them is Wicked PDF:

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf